# Input in R console

Tags: r

a is more than 1 and b is less than 1000. How do I input in a and b in R console instead of defining in the R script? I have read about the readline function but don't really understand it well.

```
a <- 3
b <- 4

y <- a*b
y

if((y %% 2) == 0) {
  print(paste(y,"is Even"))
} else {
  print(paste(y,"is Odd"))
}
```

Comment: you mean you want to read the a and b from console?

Comment: Yes, define that a is more than 1, b is less than 1000, and use console to input any numbers for a and b

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readline()` function.

Example:

```
my.name <- readline(prompt="Enter name: ")
my.age <- readline(prompt="Enter age: ")
# convert character into integer
my.age <- as.integer(my.age)
print(paste("Hi,", my.name, "next year you will be", my.age+1, "years old."))
```

[example](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/examples/user-input/)

Answer (score 0):

By just changing your first two lines using `readline` and wrapping the entire thing in `{}` You can combine your script into a clause.

```
{
a <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter a: ")) # Read in from console and change to number
b <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter b: ")) # Read in from console and change to number

y <- a*b
y

if((y %% 2) == 0) {
  print(paste(y,"is Even"))
} else {
  print(paste(y,"is Odd"))
}   
}
```

This allows you to run the whole thing from top to bottom and take your inputs consecutively. You can also make this into a function.